# I have this output from scraping an image from a website

Tags: python, image, screen-scraping

When i request an image from a url I am using this code.

from urllib.request import urlretrieve

import requests

image_url = "https://www.coinspot.com.au/public/img/coinmd/steem.png?v=180"

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)

Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

response = requests.get(image_url, headers=headers)

print(response.content)

The stuff I get back looks like this (small sample) -

b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x00\x80\x00\x00\x00\x80
\x1f\xc9\x17\x1f\xc9\x17\x1f\xc9\x17\x1f\xc9\x17\x1f\xc9\x17\x1f\xc9\x
c9\x17\x1f\xc9\x17\x1f\xc9\x17\x1f\xc9\x17\x1f\xc9\x17\x1f\xc9\x17\x1f
\x1f\xc9\x17\x1f\xc9\x17\x1f\xc9\x17\x1f\xc9\x17\x1f\xc9\x17\x1f\xc9\x
c9\x17\x1f\xc9\x17\x1f\xc9\x17\x1f\xc9\x17\x1f\xc9\x17\x1f\xc9\x17\x1f
ca\x02\t\xc4\x05\r\xc5\n\x13\xc6\x03\x0b\xc4\x08\x10\xc6\x0e\x17\xc7\x
dc\xfd\xfd\xff\x85\x89\xe3Y_\xd9JP\xd5(0\xce\xf7\xf8\xfe\xec\xed\xfbSX

Anyone know if this can be converted into a png file? I have no idea what I am looking at. When i save the output to a png file it doesnt show, but get a message, its too big or corrupt.

Answer (score 0):

Its hex for the image

You can simply write it to file with .png extension like this

```
data = bytes.fromhex(str(response.content)[2:])

with open('image.png', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(data)
```

Comment: I just tried the above -   File "C:\Crypto\imageget.py", line 14, in <module>
    data = bytes.fromhex(response.content[2:])
TypeError: fromhex() argument must be str, not bytes

So I changed it to -

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Crypto\imageget.py", line 14, in <module>
    data = str.fromhex(response.content[2:])
AttributeError: type object 'str' has no attribute 'fromhex'

Comment: How do you go to next line when commenting?

Comment: I have made a edit to my answer..can u check now

Comment: Ok! Tried that and this time I get the error - ValueError: non-hexadecimal number found in fromhex() arg at position 0 the input code at position 1 looks like this - b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x0 seems to be whining about b' or a least the b